# Many-to-many self-referential relantionships with FastAPI and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm challenging with a self-referential relationship in SQLAlchemy. I'm working on a back-end that handles the subscription to a campus and I have to record the siblings relation between two kids.
Following the SQLAlchemy documentation I'm arrived to the following solution, that works fine for an half.

```
siblings=Table('siblings',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('sibling1_id', UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('kids.id')),
    Column('sibling2_id', UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('kids.id'))
)

class Kid(Base):
    __tablename__="kids"
    id=Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name=Column(String)
    surname=Column(String)
    birthday=Column(Date)
    birthplace=Column(String)
    school_class=Column(Enum(SchoolClass))
    allergies=Column(String)
    note=Column(String)
    size=Column(Enum(KidSize))
    subscriptions=relationship("Subscription", 
                            backref="kid", 
                            uselist=True)
    parents=relationship("Parent", secondary="parents_children", 
                            backref="children",
                            uselist=True)
    siblings=relationship("Kid", secondary="siblings", 
                            primaryjoin=id==siblings.c.sibling1_id,
                            secondaryjoin=id==siblings.c.sibling2_id, 
                            back_populates='siblings',
                            uselist=True)
```

When I have created two different instances for Kid class, I add the siblings relationship adding one kid to the siblings list of the other, in the following way.

```
def add_sibling(db: Session, name1:str, surname1:str, name2:str, surname2:str):
    logger.debug("Adding new brother to %s %s", name1, surname1)
    sibling1_model=get_kid_by_name_surname(db, name1, surname1)
    sibling2_model=get_kid_by_name_surname(db, name2, surname2)

    sibling1_model.siblings.append(sibling2_model)
    db.commit()
    return True
```

The problem arises when I query the model of the two kid, for sibling1_model I have the information required and the siblings list contains the instance of sibling2_model, but the viceversa is not true, in fact, the sibling list of sibling2_model is empty.

Any idea on how to solve this unexpected behaviour?

I follow the SQLAlchemy documentation about the self-referential relentionship and try different solution found on the internet, but they did not work.

I also tried to use `backref` keyword instead of back_populates, but this creates a new attribute for my class and I need that the list of sibling is the same attribute for both the instances.